# Algorithms to count perfect matchings in near planar graphs

Tags: algorithms, perfect-matchings, pfaffian

It is well known that counting perfect matchings is tractable in planar graphs (due to Kastelyn).

I am interested in classes of (for lack of a better word) "near" planar graphs (1-planar, bounded genus etc.) where counting perfect matchings is also tractable.

Comment: This is probably not exactly what you're looking for, but for certain graphs embedded on a cylinder there are formulas as nice as the famous formulas for grid graphs: see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.07229

Comment: Ciucu's paper, [Enumeration of Perfect Matchings in Graphs with Reflective Symmetry](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81988833.pdf), has a factorization theorem that applies to symmetric bipartite graphs that are not necessarily planar. In the paper, he shows how to apply the factorization theorem to enumerate perfect matchings of a variety of graphs. I think his examples are all planar, but they don't have to be. In particular if you have a non-planar graph with bilateral symmetry that reduces to a planar graph after applying the factorization theorem, then you can count the perfect matchings.

Answer (score 5):

Graphs of bounded genus (both orientable or non-orientable):

G. Tesler, Matchings in Graphs on Non-orientable Surfaces, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B,
Volume 78, Issue 2 (2000), 198-231.
https://doi.org/10.1006/jctb.1999.1941